# Google Form and Group email

Tags: email, google-forms

I have set up a group email that I'd like to use within a Google Form. Currently the Google Form is pre-filled with my personal email and I'd like to change it to the group email.

Any help in learning how to update the email account is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

FormEmailer will let control who the email is sent to and what is sent.  https://sites.google.com/site/formemailer/